# Can't find reference Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have some problems with the references. But first let me clear the 
circumstances. I use Win7, VS 2010, .NET Framework 3.5.

I have a project previously worked on by a colleague.
Now I have the project for some further changes and the programm does not find the `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback` reference.

I have tried adding to manually but I do not find it in the given path.

Does anyone have another solution, which provides me the right way?

Comment: DirectX has its own SDK (part of Windows SDK?) so you don't get that within Visual Studio by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a reference to the *Microsoft DirectX SDK*. You would have to download and install that first via [**Microsoft's website**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812), then the DLL-files can be found in `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0`.